# How can I lock the working hours column?

Tags: microsoft-project

In Microsoft Project 2010, whenever I attempt to edit the resource assigned to a task, it changes my work hours while keeping the dates the same.  However, this is exactly the opposite of what I want, I want to figure the dates based on the resource time assigned to the estimated work amount.

**How can I "lock" the work amount so it will not be recalculated?**

Answer (score 2):

1. Add the column 'Type'
2. Change the type for the task to 'Fixed Work'